# In java how does one loop through each character in a word and then identify what point that character has got and keep adding the point for the word

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, java.util.scanner, filereader

This is for an assignment that I have not been able to wrap my head around. This is my first real take on Java and so far I am finding it quite difficult. I have attached the assignment [PDF](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AsOBZ0KxzD2XoFbN3vQYf88nKbZS) and it is the *`pointsProblem`* section I have been unsuccessful with.

So far I have:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordGames {

    static HashMap<Character, Integer> valueOfCharacter;
    static final String DICTIONARY = "dictionary.txt";
    static int i;
    static int wordCount;
    static String line;
    static String substringWordList;
    static String[] randomSubstringResults = new String[23];
    static FileReader listOfWordsFile;
    static Scanner substringProblemInput;
    static Scanner wordListFileScanner;

    static {

        substringProblemInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            listOfWordsFile = new FileReader(DICTIONARY);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        wordListFileScanner = new Scanner(listOfWordsFile);

        while (wordListFileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = wordListFileScanner.nextLine();
            randomSubstringResults[wordCount] = line;
            wordCount++;
        }
    }

    static {

        valueOfCharacter = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        valueOfCharacter.put('l', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('e', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('n', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('i', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('o', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('r', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('t', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('s', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('a', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('u', 1);
        valueOfCharacter.put('d', 2);
        valueOfCharacter.put('g', 2);
        valueOfCharacter.put('b', 3);
        valueOfCharacter.put('c', 3);
        valueOfCharacter.put('m', 3);
        valueOfCharacter.put('p', 3);
        valueOfCharacter.put('f', 4);
        valueOfCharacter.put('h', 4);
        valueOfCharacter.put('v', 4);
        valueOfCharacter.put('w', 4);
        valueOfCharacter.put('y', 4);
        valueOfCharacter.put('k', 5);
        valueOfCharacter.put('j', 8);
        valueOfCharacter.put('x', 8);
        valueOfCharacter.put('q', 10);
        valueOfCharacter.put('z', 10);

    }

    static void gameMenuSelection() throws FileNotFoundException {

        int getSelectionOption;

        Scanner gameMenuSelectionInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Word Games program menu.");
        System.out.println("Select from one of the following options.");
        System.out.println("1. Substring problem.");
        System.out.println("2. Points problem.");
        System.out.println("3. Exit.");
        System.out.print("Enter your selection: ");

        getSelectionOption = gameMenuSelectionInput.nextInt();
            switch (getSelectionOption) {
                case 1:
                    substringProblemGame();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pointsProblemGame();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("\n" + "Goodbye!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid option. Try again.");
                    break;
            }
        }

    static void substringProblemGame() throws FileNotFoundException {

        String randomSubstringInput;
        String wordHasInfix = " - infix";
        String wordHasPrefix = " - prefix";
        String wordHasSuffix = " - suffix";
        String nothingIsFound = " - not found";

        System.out.println("\n" + "Substring problem.");

        System.out.print("Enter a substring: ");
        randomSubstringInput = substringProblemInput.next();


        for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {

            substringWordList = randomSubstringResults[i];
            boolean found = false;

            if (randomSubstringResults[i].startsWith(randomSubstringInput)) {
                substringWordList = substringWordList + wordHasPrefix;
                found = true;
            }
            if (randomSubstringResults[i].endsWith(randomSubstringInput)) {
                substringWordList = substringWordList + wordHasSuffix;
                found = true;
            }
            if (randomSubstringResults[i].contains(randomSubstringInput)) {
                substringWordList = substringWordList + wordHasInfix;
                found = true;
            }
            if (!found) {
                System.out.println(substringWordList + nothingIsFound);
            } else {
                System.out.println(substringWordList);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        gameMenuSelection();
    }

    static void pointsProblemGame() throws FileNotFoundException {


        System.out.println("Points problem.");

        }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


        gameMenuSelection();

    }
}
```

I tried implementing a `HashMap` but couldn't figure out how to get it working. I have tried to do this from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-count-occurrences-character/?ref=rp) but again unsuccessful. I may just be useless or something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: `List<Character> onePointCharacters = "aeilnorstu".chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList());`, Or perhaps even better: `Set<Character> onePointCharacterSet =  "aeilnorstu".chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toSet());`.  Then you just need to work out how to turn your string into words, and then figure out accumulate a sum of over the list of characters in each word.

Comment: That seems more advance to what I think I am required to provide. I am struggling with Java, so is there something else you may suggest please?

Comment: An array might be better to use an array. The value of a lower case character c would be val[c - 'a'] = x.

Answer (score 0):

You have filled the HashMap with the letters and their associated scores. Now you should be able to grab the associated score for each word by iterating over each character within it and grabbing the value from the Map. For Example,

```
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < yourArray[i].length(); j++) {
            score += hashMap.get(yourArray[i].getCharAt(j));
        }
    }
```

Here is the docs for the hashmap where you can see all of its methods and their uses. The get method takes in the key, which in your case would be the character, and returns the value(the associated score).
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html